# Using jQuery to hide/show a Panel inside of a table

Tags: jquery, asp.net

I have an ASP.NET web form, with table.  Inside the table, I have a radiobuttonlist control and below that I have a Panel.  Inside the panel are several  tags with other web controls.

What I want to do is have the panel display or hide based on the selection in the radiobuttonlist.  In my jQuery I have this:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {    
    $('#<%= rblCarrier.ClientID%>').find('input:radio').click(function() {
        var selVal = $('#<%= rblCarrier.ClientID %>').find('input:checked').val();
        if (selVal == "1") $("#mydiv").show("fast");                
        else  $("#mydiv").hide("fast");            
    })
});
```

If I replace `$("#mydiv").show("fast");` with an `alert` the `alert` displays, so I know everything up to that point is working.

Remember, my asp.net panel is inside of an HTML table.

All I want to do is show the contents of the panel if the radio button value is "1", otherwise hide it.

Comment: Is `#mydiv` the descendant of a hidden element?

Comment: Can you find the radio buttons? What do you get with this code: `console.log($('#<%= rblCarrier.ClientID%>').find('input:radio'))` ?

Comment: What's the markup for `myDiv`?

Comment: Yes, I find the radio buttons.  As I said, that alert works, so I know I am getting the value of the rbl.

Comment: #mydiv is just a simple div.  <div id="mydiv">  I also removed it and tried with just a <asp:Panel ID="myph" runat="server"> and referenced the myph with its ClientID.  Still same result.  I am using master page, so I also tried by the the ct100 type of ID in my reference...no change.

Answer (score 0):

I gave up on this.  Nobody on any forum had code that actually worked with a .NET panel or placeholder.  So I took an easier route.  I removed the panel and instead embedded a table inside of the table row.  I gave the table an ID and then it was easy to show/hide it with the jQuery.  Apparently .NET server controls don't play nice with jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

Guys I was also struggling with this problem (Using jQuery to hide/show a Panel but in my case was with RadioButtonList and is not inside a table) and searched many posts and found no answer but I was able to make it work here's how I did...

My code is as follows:

```
<div>
            <p class="space">3.2. ACCOMMODATION (*)</p>

            <asp:RadioButtonList ID="accomodation" runat="server" RepeatDirection="Horizontal" RepeatLayout="Flow" Width="500px">
                <asp:ListItem Text="Not Required" Value="Not Required"></asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Text="Required" Value="Required"></asp:ListItem>
            </asp:RadioButtonList>

            <asp:Panel ID="PanelAccommodation" runat="server">
                <p>
                    Number of nights (*):
                     <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator12" runat="server" ControlToValidate="numberOfNights" ForeColor="red" ErrorMessage="<- Required"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                </p>
                <asp:TextBox ID="numberOfNights" runat="server" Width="50px"></asp:TextBox>

                <ajaxToolkit:FilteredTextBoxExtender ID="FilteredTextBoxExtender1" TargetControlID="numberOfNights"
                    FilterType="Numbers" runat="server">
                </ajaxToolkit:FilteredTextBoxExtender>

                <p>Preferred Hotel:</p>
                <asp:TextBox ID="preferredHotel" runat="server" Width="450px"></asp:TextBox>

                <p>Preferred Hotel URL:</p>
                <asp:TextBox ID="preferredHotelURL" runat="server" Width="450px"></asp:TextBox>
            </asp:Panel>
        </div>
```

and the jquery function I used:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
            $("#MainContent_PanelAccommodation").hide("fast");
            $('#<%= accomodation.ClientID%>').find('input:radio').click(function () {
                var selVal = $('#<%= accomodation.ClientID %>').find('input:checked').val();
                if (selVal == "Required") {
                    $("#MainContent_PanelAccommodation").show("fast");
                }
                if (selVal == "Not Required") {
                    $("#MainContent_PanelAccommodation").hide("fast");
                }
            })
        });
```

notice that the ID on the jquery has "MainContent" while that ID on the HTML doesn't this is because if you inspect your code and look for your panel it will also probably show and ID similar to MainContent_PanelAccommodation since it inherits from:

```
<asp:Content ID="Content3" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">
```

Hope this helps people struggling with the same problem...